# Custom host name for Azure Media Services via new portal

Tags: azure, azure-media-services

How can I add custom host name for my Azure Media Service streaming endpoint on the new portal? I know how to add it on the classic portal, but managing AMS on classic portal will be disabled after 10 January 2017, and the new portal doesn't seem to have an option for that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

New portal doesn't include custom domain names since it was an advanced feature mostly targeted for prodev. You can set it using either code or using [`Azure Media Explorer`](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/managing-media-workflows-with-the-new-azure-media-services-explorer-tool/) tool.

Cenk

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Another question if you don't mind, is it possible to use HTTPS for custom host name?

Comment: @Cenkd...I took the opportunity to edit your answer and included the link for Azure Media Explorer tool. I hope you don't mind. Thank you for providing the answer. I came to know about this tool from your answer.

Answer (score 0):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/media/operations/streamingendpoint has the details about custom hostname. See the section "CustomHostNames". But it is not doable in portal and you have to use media explorer.

Please note that currently SSL is not supported for custom hostname in AMS. Above link also confirms the same.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)